# Xcode not showing autocomplete for blocks in parse.com

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I had this problem lately:

how it shows
[image]

the auto complete doesn't complete the block (it used to).

how it needs to be
[image: works ok]

Comment: The autocomplete looks fine right there, what isn't happening exactly?

Comment: I added a link to show what is wrong with the Xcode behaviour

Comment: It's not very clear from your description, but from what I can see, the first picture is correct autocompletion, and the second one is the broken autocompletion you're currently experiencing. i.e. It is your contacts project that's having the problem. Is that correct?

Comment: contacts is working good, the other one is working not good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Used pervious generation of Xcode , it worked great.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you have

- Start writing to call the autocomplete menu
- Press enter to create the block
- Press Tab to go to the next parameter
- Hit enter again to write the parameter
- (Repeat these last 2 steps if necessary.)
- Then fill the inside of the block(s).

If that doesn't work, try the following (it's a bit of a pain because XCode isn't reliable)

- Make sure you imported the right files (and that the current file knows Parse, in this case)
- Try cleaning the project
- Try quitting and restarting Xcode (not just the red button, but a real app restart).

Comment: look at the requested result and find out what i mean by the problem with autocomplete

Comment: I added some ideas in my answer

Comment: tried all of that, i am using original code of parse.com and blank project, it still depends to use it like that it also uses PFquery init not as instancetype

Comment: Do you still get autocomplete with other methods ? like objectAtIndex: or stringWithFormat?

Answer (score 0):

I've found you have to manually add the block syntax yourself.

If you go to the Parse header file and then use that to link to the PFUserResult typedef, it gives you the list of typdefs:

```
typedef void (^PFBooleanResultBlock)(BOOL succeeded, NSError *PF_NULLABLE_S error);
typedef void (^PFIntegerResultBlock)(int number, NSError *PF_NULLABLE_S error);
typedef void (^PFArrayResultBlock)(NSArray *PF_NULLABLE_S objects, NSError *PF_NULLABLE_S error);
typedef void (^PFObjectResultBlock)(PFObject *PF_NULLABLE_S object,  NSError *PF_NULLABLE_S error);
typedef void (^PFSetResultBlock)(NSSet *PF_NULLABLE_S channels, NSError *PF_NULLABLE_S error);
typedef void (^PFUserResultBlock)(PFUser *PF_NULLABLE_S user, NSError *PF_NULLABLE_S error);
typedef void (^PFDataResultBlock)(NSData *PF_NULLABLE_S data, NSError *PF_NULLABLE_S error);
typedef void (^PFDataStreamResultBlock)(NSInputStream *PF_NULLABLE_S stream, NSError *PF_NULLABLE_S error);
typedef void (^PFStringResultBlock)(NSString *PF_NULLABLE_S string, NSError *PF_NULLABLE_S error);
typedef void (^PFIdResultBlock)(PF_NULLABLE_S id object, NSError *PF_NULLABLE_S error);
typedef void (^PFProgressBlock)(int percentDone);
```

You have to then copy paste it manually. It's a bit of a pain, and I'm not sure why the autocomplete stopped working.

And don't forget to add the ^!

Answer (score 0):

This might make your next steps clearer than the answers, which may or may not have answered your question (I can't tell). Try this:

The following code shows you how to set up blocks-within-a-block so that Xcode will auto-complete both the parameters and return values when you use the block:

In the header file:

```
typedef BOOL (^Condition)(void);
typedef void (^Success)(void);
typedef void (^Failure)(void);
typedef void (^Task)(Condition condition, Success success, Failure failure);

@property (copy, nonatomic, readwrite) Task task;
@property (copy, nonatomic, readwrite) Condition condition;
@property (copy, nonatomic, readwrite) Success success;
@property (copy, nonatomic, readwrite) Failure failure;
```

In the implementation file:

```
- (Task)task
{
    return ^(Condition condition, Success success, Failure failure) {
        if (condition())
        {
            success();
        } else {
            failure();
        }
    };
}
```

In the implementation file of any class granted access to the Task property, being typing the path to the property, as well as the property name itself, until Xcode auto-completes the rest:

```
AppServices.task(<#^BOOL(void)condition#>, <#^(void)success#>, <#^(void)failure#>)
```

Press the tab key to advance to the first parameter (`condition`), and then press Return; repeat for the remaining two parameters (`success` and `failure`):

```
AppServices.task(^BOOL{
        <#code#>
    }, ^{
        <#code#>
    }, ^{
        <#code#>
    })
```

Replace `code` with your code, making sure to return the appropriate value for any block that returns a non-void type )(`condition` returns `BOOL`):

```
[class].task(^BOOL{
        return TRUE;
    }, ^{
        NSLog(@"TRUE");
    }, ^{
        NSLog(@"FALSE");
    });
```

In this example, the Task block executes either the `Success` or `Failure` block depending on the return value of the conditional specified in the `Condition` block.

My intended use is far more complex and pragmatic than this example; but, as far as "how to do it" goes, it will do.